# Rails video and image tag not working in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, assets

[image: THIS IS HOW IT LOOKS LIKE IN THE BROWSER]

[image: THIS IS THE HTML.ERB IN]

[image: THIS IS MY SHOW.ERB FILE]

Hi I'm very new to rails and came up with this issue. I need your help. Please.

Activeadmin parses the code as raw text so i used`<%= raw(@classroom.body) %>` in my show.erb to unescape the html tags. but i figured this is the reason why it escapes the ruby video_tag.

I checked out the activeadmin arbre but didn't understand it. i also tried using html video tags but for some reason it shows the video template but doesn't connect to the video file in app/assets/videos.

But when I parse the HTML code directly in the show.erb, the video works perfectly.

The video file can be found in app/assets/videos/Heather.mp4
**`<%= video_tag "Heather.mp4", :controls => true %>`**

The first picture is how it looks like in the web browser
The second is the html code in active admin
The third is my show.erb file

Comment: Sorry, could you include a screenshot. We would need more info. Also Is this an error message from active admin? or you just see on your view the video tags?

Comment: Did you type that code into a WYSIWYG or what? Or is it in a file? If so, which file? The code is correct but it's not parsing, obviously. So it's probably added to the wrong area.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio the code is in active admin adding pictures of everything asap.

Comment: @WesFoster the post is in activeadmin. but parsing through the show.erb file. adding pictures for better clarification.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `raw` method produces raw HTML, not raw ERB. You won't be able to parse your `<%= %>` tags from there.

Reference the [Rails Docs for `raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw)

Comment: What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @DavidAdafia Just embed the video using HTML

Comment: Okay will do. Will let you know how it goes asap. Thanks @WesFoster